# What is IDES SAP?

Tags: sap-erp

Can somebody please explain to me what exactly SAP IDES is? I am new with SAP, and this is the term I found several times so far, but could not find out the exact meaning of it. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming related question according to the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

The acronym IDES stands for Internet Demonstration and Evaluation System. It contains master data and business scenarios that represent a hypothetical company. What is more important is that all SAP training courses are built around the data and customizing from [SAP IDES](http://sap-certification.info/sap-ides/). For this reason, if you want to do the practical exercises from any SAP training course, an access to SAP remote server with IDES is required.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

They are fake data for SAP ERP system just in training purposes!

EX:
 For Germany we can use company code 1000 but for USA we use 3000 and so on ...

Company code is  is a legal entity that is required by law to provide financial records according to country-specific regulations.

Answer (score -1):

SAP-IDES  stands for "International Demonstration and Education System". There are all main processes implemented.

I run SAP-IDES in a VM-Ware-Image on my lap top and it's really fast.

Comment: How did you get that image? I'd like to have a copy, too!